# AnyLogic Simple Process Memory Blowup

Tags: memory, simulation, anylogic

I am simulating a process in AnyLogic.

My agents are available as 'raw materials' in time t=0. I have 30,000 many of the same agents at the beginning of the simulation. Hence, for the source module, I am referring to a database, where the *multiple agents per arrival* box is ticked and the *agents per arrival* number is taken from a database (which is 30,000 there).

I am using a dummy process, where these agents arrive at the "source" and immediately go out from the "sink". When I have, e.g., 30 many agents coming there is not a problem. However, when I have 30,000 the memory blows up and the simulation stops. I don't know why there is a problem. What is the difference between 30 and 30,000 agents in such a simple example?

**ScreenShot:**

My simple model looks like:

[image]

And the database which works:

[image]

And the quantities are called via:
[image]

And all done:

[image]

But when I make the first products 30,000 many, then it gets stuck in the arrival date:

[image]

Moreover, my agent class is here:

[image]

And it shows on the Projects view as:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rectangular node has "Visible on upper agent" set, try unticking that.

There is currently a bug in AnyLogic when this is set and an agent's (or a population of agents') presentation is *not* shown in an upper-level agent, which causes extreme slowdowns as you are experiencing (particularly for larger numbers of agents; even, it seems, if the "Visible on upper agent" presentation elements are *not* in the agent type that there are many instances of).

In your case, your rectangular node is in the top-level agent Main, which is by definition a 'child' of the experiment from a presentation point of view --- it is also meaningless to set "Visible on upper agent" here (but it still seems to trigger the bug in some cases).

(Having said all this, the bug did not cause the '500 error' in the cases I saw so this might not work.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload a screenshot of your source and dbase table?

If you tick that box, it sounds like you are creating 30000x30000 agents?

In any case, it is not a good strategy to model that many agents if it is not necessary. In your case, you could either combine 30000 materials into 1 agent (until they are broken apart?) or use the material library or a SD setup.

Only model individual agents if you really need it.

Comment: Also, I need to have 30,000 of these agents because each of their parameters will be changed in the very next process...

Comment: thx. Weird indeed. When does the model stop? Looks like the engine gets killed while agents are still being produced. Also, have you tested with a queue in between? And when is the moment the model starts breaking (i.e. how many agents per arrival)? Does it vary or is it an exact number?

Comment: The model stops at the exact arrival time. No one arrives if I have ~10,000. I now tried with 5,000, it is very slow and after freezing ~2-3 seconds it finishes the process. Maybe it is because I have too many of the agents, but I need to have millions!! Do you think to define all the agents which are already available as `arrival at t=0' is wrong?

Comment: You do not need millions of agents! Absolutely not :-) How is your agent class set up? Can you upload a screenshot of it as well? Why does your model stop at the arrival time? Don't you want to do something with the agents eventually?

Comment: I followed your approach and made one Agent with 30,000 quantity, etc. I added an ss of my Agent class. I have no idea why it stops :(

Comment: well, work backwards. Simplify your agent down to having only 1 parameter. If it still crashes, it is not due to agent complexity. Then work forward: start with a model from scratch and create 30k agents without a dbase. Become Sherlock Holmes and find the root cause. If you found it, report back :-)

Comment: Figured out something. If I don't specify the 'location of arrival' which is a rectangular node from the space markup part then everything works. Otherwise, when I connect, the memory has issues... I don't know but this is weird